# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.StringBuilder from code using java.lang.StringBuffer

Tags: java, command-line, package, stringbuilder, classnotfoundexception

I know there are plenty of questions regarding this error, but I haven't found it easy to find one exactly like mine.

Here goes.

I have a pretty small application that writes DB data to a csv file and then uploads it to a server. I have it running on my local box out of eclipse which is great, but the final version needs to be run as a cron job on a server box from command line.

I'm working on the command line call for the main java class and its giving me lots of trouble.

My dependency structure is as such:
My classes

- package=gtechReconcile
- classes= GtechReconciler.java, CSVFile.java, QueryMachine.java, FTPSender.java

My external libs

- ojdbc14.zip
- edtftpj.jar

I run the following line in the terminal in the directory above the compile source package (ie /path/to/classes where /path/to/classes/gtechReconcile/ has all the compiled class files) This path is the current directory when the command line is run :

```
java -cp /<snip>/lib/ojdbc14.zip:/<snip>/lib/edtftpj.jar:/path/to/classes gtechReconcile.GtechReconciler
```

The error then tells me it can't find java.lang.StringBuilder, even though this does not exist in my code. I use a StringBuffer, which apparently StringBuilder has replaced since Java5. Perhaps the java compiler converted this to StringBuilder, which the jvm then does not resolve?

What am I missing here?

EDIT : added error from prompt (clarified where this executes from and what is present in the package folder):

```
[gtechReconcile]$ pwd
/path/to/
[gtechReconcile]$ cd classes/gtechReconcile/
[gtechReconcile]$ ls
CSVFile.class  FTPSender.class  GtechReconciler.class  QueryMachine.class  reports
[gtechReconcile]$ cd ..
[classes]$ ls
gtechReconcile
[classes]$ java -cp .:/path/to/lib/ojdbc14.zip:/path/to/lib/edtftpj.jar gtechReconcile.GtechReconciler
Creating file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: while resolving class: gtechReconcile.CSVFile
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.Class.initializeClass() (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at gtechReconcile.GtechReconciler.main(java.lang.String[]) (Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.StringBuilder not found in [file:./, file:/opt/mms_tstt2/gtechReconcile/lib/ojdbc14.zip, file:/opt/mms_tstt2/gtechReconcile/lib/edtftpj.jar, file:/usr/share/java/libgcj-3.4.6.jar, file:./, core:/]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at gnu.gcj.runtime.VMClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_FindClass(_Jv_Utf8Const, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_BytecodeVerifier.verify_instructions_0() (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_VerifyMethod(_Jv_InterpMethod) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_PrepareClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at _Jv_WaitForState(java.lang.Class, int) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.linkClass0(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
...2 more
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're on some Unix flavour?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the server is RedHat, not 100% though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is raised when you create a new StringBuilder in your CSVFile class. Google tells me it's a frequent problem with GCJ, use an official Sun JVM. It usally resolves this kind of problem.

---

The `gtechReconcile` folder is assumed to contains all the class files in the `gtechReconcile` package.

In example, if you have `/path/to/classes/gtechReconcile/GtechReconciler.class`, you have two options.

1. Go to `/path/to/classes`, add to the classpath the current directory (`.`) and run `java` as you did before.
2. Add `/path/to/classes` to the classpath and run `java` wherever you like.

Comment: Correct, I suppose I wasn't clear enough, but /<snip>/bin is == /path/to/classes and is in the class path. I tried it with . in the classpath for sanity. Edited my post to use /path/to/classes which seems like a more clear representation of the directory

Comment: That's okay. I do need the ojdbc for the QueryMachine class to connect to our DB, I'm very confident the zip file is okay though because I have used it in a handful of other applications we run.

Comment: Thanks frm, nice find. I ignored the StringBuilder because my code does not explicitly call it. It must be in one of the Java File or IO classes. Turns out the JVM linked to the aliased java command on the server is from 2002. Ran the commands with java6 and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

The default classpath (if you don't specify one) is the current directory (".").

However, if you specify a classpath, java will use that instead of the default, thus removing the current directory.

The solution to your problem is simple: add the "current directory" to your class path, such as:

```
java -cp .:/<snip>/lib/ojdbc14.zip:/<snip>/lib/edtftpj.jar:/<snip>/bin/ gtechReconcile.GtechReconciler
```

Comment: . = /<snip>/bin  and adding it has not improved the situation